# Android -purpose of useLevel in shape tag

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, layer-list

What is the purpose of android shape xml tag useLevel attribute ? This is in respect to a layer-list but should not matter. 
 From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html) i found the meanging of the useLevel tag:

> Indicates whether the drawable's level affects the way the gradient is drawn.

So if i have the following xml snippet:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadius="15dp"
    android:thickness="10dp"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <solid android:color="#ababf2" />

    <size
        android:height="50dp"
        android:width="50dp" />
</shape>
```

then with the useLevel=true, the ring is disabled.  It must be false for the ring to appear.  But what is the purpose of this attribute ? The docs are not clear.

Comment: `The docs are not clear` - like this never happened before on Android, right? :)

Comment: [This portion of the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) has `android:useLevel` on the `<gradient>` element, with a description of "true if this is used as a LevelListDrawable." `LevelListDrawable` definitely has the notion of a level. That being said, I don't understand the relationship here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is for ProgressBars. For example [this gist](https://gist.github.com/TWiStErRob/08d5807e396740e52c90) uses a ring shape as a progress drawable.

res/drawable/github_232_circular.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
       android:shape="ring"
       android:thickness="3.8sp"
       android:useLevel="true">
    <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
</shape>
```

In your layout:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/github_232_circular"
/>
```

Basically, `useLevel` makes it so the drawable can be drawn partially. For example there is a method [ImageView.setImageLevel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageLevel(int)) that lets you set a "level," e.g. 25% progress, so the ring drawable would be drawn as a quarter-circle. And [ProgressBar.setProgress()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setProgress(int)) does the same thing, updating the "level" of the drawable you've set on the ProgressBar.

Comment: so your saying that the useLevel makes the progressbar circular ? im still not following you as the shape you provided is alraedy a ring.

Comment: `useLevel` makes it so the drawable can be drawn partially. For example there is a method `ImageView.setImageLevel()` that lets you set a "level," e.g. 25% progress, so the ring drawable would be drawn as a quarter-circle. And ProgressBar sets the drawable "level" whenever you use `ProgressBar.setProgress()`. I'll update my answer with this extra detail.